# When you search the documentation and there're zero results it should say "Your search returned no matches."

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, documentation

see the diference when there're no results that macthed in Questions
[image]

And in the documentation

you have to gues if your browser is hanging or there're no matching results,

see image

[image: Blank]

the page is blank as white snow.

I would also add a suggestion that if nothing is matched SO should Suggest and link to Info of that topic

EX: I searched for "tampermonkey" nothing matched it should suggest to view https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tampermonkey/info

Comment: Not sure if this be categorized as a bug, more like a 'feature request'.

Comment: @AndrewL. of course. feeding back to the user with a blank page is intended behaviour

Comment: Unfortunately this is the least of search problems. documentation is very much being designed/developed for those who want to write and review documentation and not for those who want to actually read it. We seem to care more about rep than whether the documentation actually works for those who would read it

Comment: I think they mirrored the behavior of the /tags page.

Comment: Based on a comparison of what I've seen on Q&A before and after the Documentation launch, I'm not sure the intended audience *is* reading it.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the next build we'll be showing a message explaining there were no results.

In cases where the tag exists, we'll also show a link to that tag's question page:

> [image]